# MySQL delete trigger not working, gives error 1442

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL trigger. I am trying to get temperature readings from a Raspberry Pi into a local database on my computer. This part works, but then the temperatures from that table needs to update every so often and the old values need to go in an archive table. The archive part is not done yet because I first want it working that the values update. I tried to do this with the following trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS temperature;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER temperature 
BEFORE INSERT ON coldroomtemperatures
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.ColdRoomSensorNumber = "5"
    THEN DELETE FROM coldroomtemperatures WHERE ColdRoomSensorNumber = "5";
    END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

I have tried using "BEFORE" and "AFTER" but both don't work. When I try to run the temperature reading on my Raspberry Pi it will only run once and then stop with the error code: "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'coldroomtemperatures' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"

Does anyone know the problem with my trigger?

Comment: You can't update same table which use in trigger. Probably, you can change you code to update table's row instead of delete/insert?

Comment: this is also called a MUTATION.  one way to solve would be to make a seperate loading table - then have the trigger manage the 'real' tables.

Comment: run the delete before inserting, there is no good reason to run this in a trigger